# "Like us" or "like we do"

Tags: grammar

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning?

> They go to school **like we do**.
>
> They go to school **like us**.

I know the first one is correct, but I am not sure if the second one is correct too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They both mean that ‘they’ and ‘we’ resemble one another in going to school. In the first sentence, *like* is a subordinating conjunction.  In the second, it’s a preposition. Some people object to the use of *like* as a conjunction. There are really no grounds for doing so, but if your readers are likely to be among them, then it’s safer to use *as* if you choose the construction in the first sentence.

Comment: I don't think it's quite that simple.  There clearly *are* grounds for objecting to 'like', (since some people do so) whether you think them sensible or not. And 'They go to school as us' implies impersonation. Myself I would say 'like us' informally, or 'in the same way we do' formally.

Comment: There are some people who object to ***anything.*** That's no reason to pay attention to them, or to consider that "grounds" for objection.

Comment: @TimLymington: Quite right about the point in your second sentence. Careless drafting on my part and now amended. On the substance, the ever dependable ‘Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ notes that ‘There never was a general principle as to why "like" could not be used conjunctively, and it is now strongly supported by corpus data from around the English-speaking world.'

Comment: @Barrie: so usage is good evidence when it supports the use of *like*, but not when it supports objections to it? Cheap shot, I know, but I have never seen the point properly answered.

Comment: @TimLymington: Usage supports both. The only reason for arguing the case for 'like' is that its conjunctive use is so often questioned. What is the point to be answered?

Comment: In the deleted-and-adjusted version 'They go to school like us', what is the justification for regarding 'like' as a preposition on distributional grounds rather than a [n ex-] subordinator on deep-functional grounds? The paraphrase for 'They go to school like us' needs a rewrite to say 'They go to school in the same way that we do / go to school', demanding the subordinator.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the sample sentences are incorrect. The first should use "as," not "like"--"like" is appropriate with nouns or noun phrases only.  For example, "I feel like a winner" is correct, but not, "I feel like I cannot lose."  The latter should be, "I feel as though I cannot lose."  The second sample sentence should be written as, "They, like us, go to school."